# How to extract part of each line and create a list

Tags: bash

I'm getting following multiline output from a command:

```
"InstanceId": "i-0e827d54c1b87fa87",
"InstanceId": "i-0c084d7a6ac86dcc2",
"InstanceId": "i-05d669152a3a67ee2",
```

I need create a list of only values e.g. `i-0e827d54c1b87fa87` so that I can iterate it later in script.

How can extract out only `i-0e827d54c1b87fa87` from `"InstanceId": "i-0e827d54c1b87fa87",` for each line of above block and create a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to do this-

```
#cut is built to do exactly this
cut -c 16-34 file

#Take the substring using awk
awk '{print substr($0, 16, 19)}' file #Take the substring using awk

#Define a double quote as delimiter and print the 4th column
awk -F\" '{print $4}' file
```

Where `file` is the output that you showed in the question. If you don't want to put that output in a file, you can pipe it to these commands.

Comment: awk -F\" '{print $4}' worked. thanks!
result of first two solutions was "InstanceId":

Comment: @SatishGadhave `cut` would be slightly faster but I would prefer `awk` as well.

If it worked I'd appreciate an accept and/or an upvote.

Comment: @SatishGadhave, that's not possible. Is the input you're using different from the input you posted in your question? `cut -c` is supposed to cut out the 16th-34th character. It shouldn't be picking up the `InstanceId` part.

Comment: you could also use `cut -d'"' -f4` in case some of the `i-0e827d54c1b87fa87` fields are not exactly the same length as the others.